# Implementing a custom QListWidgetItem?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, mouseevent, right-click

I am really stuck at the moment..
My Application can create (animation) frames with a click, these frames can either be moved, deleted or edited. I want some kind of right-click context menu to delete them.

My attempt now is creating a QListWidget, and insert QListWidgetItems (the frames) in there. I can put these Items in there, but ofcourse i have no idea on how to store the frames then.

I tried to make a new class, derived from QListWidgetItem like this:

```
    #pragma once

    #include <qobject.h>
    #include <QtGui>
    #include <Frame.h>

    class FrameItem : public QListWidgetItem
    {
    public:
        FrameItem();
        Frame frame;
        void setFrame(Frame f);
        Frame getFrame();
        int id;
        void setId(int id);
        int getId();
    };
```

This would actually work, but the itemClicked() signal does not trigger anymore.

```
void itemClicked(QListWidgetItem* item)
{   
    std::cout << item->text().toStdString() << std::endl;
};
```

If I change the parameter of itemClicked(QListWidgetItem* item) to itemClicked(FrameItem* item) the signal does not fire anymore.

Do I need to  overwrite the itemClicked() slot? If yes, how?
Is there a better approach to store much data, and give them a right-click contextmenu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The present slot's arguments must match the signal's arguments. So, you can't use a slot with `FrameItem` parameter. Use this:

```
void itemClicked(QListWidgetItem* item) {
  FrameItem* frameItem = static_cast<FrameItem*>(item);
  //...
}
```

You need to cast `QListWidgetItem` to `FrameItem`. You're allowed to do this only if you are sure that it's really `FrameItem` object. You can't use `qobject_cast` since `QListWidgetItem` doesn't inherit `QObject`, but it's still better to use `static_cast` instead of `reinterpret_cast`. If you insert only `FrameItem` items in your list, it would be OK. In other cases the perfect choice would be `dynamic_cast` because it returns null pointer if the object is not actually `FrameItem`. But it may not work if you use dynamic linking.

Aside of this, subclassing `QListWidgetItem` is not recommended. As [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget) says, `QListWidget::setItemWidget` should be used to display static content using custom Widgets, and `QListView` and `QItemDelegate` should be used in more complex cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the function signature, the signal wont trigger. The solution is much simpler, just receive a QListWidgetItem * and reinterpret_cast it to a FrameItem.

As long as you NEVER insert anything in the list that it's not a FrameItem, you will be safe.

Comment: Like this ?connect(listWidget,SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)),this,SLOT(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*))); and in the slot this: FrameItem* fi= reinterpret_cast<FrameItem*>(&item);

Comment: @Amazonasmann: That's it, only that you shouldn't be using the address of item: FrameItem* fi = reinterpret_cast<FrameItem*>(Item);

Comment: ok, now i can access the functions of FrameItem..however, item->setText() is working just fine...but when i do a item->setId(20) and in the slot i make a item->getId() the result is not not 20 but -1414812757 ..any ideas?

Comment: @Amazonasmann Is your `setId(int id)` function assigning a value to the correct variable?

Comment: maybe i should really do a qobject_cast ? but i did not figure out yet how to do it... qobject_cast<FrameItem *>(item) does not work...